# Kafka Avro - Precision change for float value

Tags: apache-kafka, floating-point, avro, confluent-schema-registry

We are pushing json records from nifi to kakfa topic using schema registry.

Schema :

```
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Name",
  "fields": [{
            "name": "latitude",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "float"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "longitude",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "float"
            ]
          }]
```

**Example 1** -

Input Record  : 
`{"import_latitude":38.090925000000,"import_longitude":8.677760000000}`

Output Record (kafka topic): `{"latitude":{"float":38.090923},"longitude":{"float":8.67776}}`

38.090925000000 --> 38.090923

**Example 2** -

Input Record  : `{"import_latitude":38.090926000000,"import_longitude":8.677760000000}`

Output Record (kafka topic): `{"latitude":{"float":38.090927},"longitude":{"float":8.67776}}`

Is this problem with kafka avro schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are getting the expected results!  This is unrelated to Avro, but to 32 bit floating point precision (i.e. 6/7 significant digits).

You can see this in Java no matter how you look at a `float`:

```java
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("38.090925000000")); // 38.090923
System.out.println((float) 8.677760000000d); // 8.67776
System.out.println(38.090926000000f); // 38.090927
System.out.println(new Double(8.677760000000).floatValue()); // 8.67776
```

It looks like your JSON geo coordinates have either 8 or 14 significant digits.

If you need to, you can bump to an Avro `DOUBLE` (15/16 significant digits) instead of a `FLOAT`, keeping in mind that some decimal text representations can't be accurately represented in binary, no matter how many bits you assign.

For many aspects, representing long/lat in a float is [accurate enough](https://xkcd.com/2170/), and a double is overkill.

Comment: I figured out the issue in similar way